# Updating the location of a horizontal line based on a slider value in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to draw a plot that has both curves based on (x, y) data and horizontal lines. I want to update the curves and lines based on the state of a slider. How can I do this?

I know how to update the curve based on the slider state, by using `ColumnDataSource`. I also know how to draw a horizontal line, by using `Span`. But I don't know how to combine these two.

For now, I am doing a hack by representing the horizontal line by an array of identical y-values, which I am storing in the `ColumnDataSource`, and by using `line()` instead of `Span`. I'm just wondering if this is the intended way to solve this problem.

I found this same question asked by user Thornhale in a 2017 comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35019983/543913). But the comment was not answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bokeh offers you the opportunity to link sources and widgets using `js_link` or `js_on_change`. In your case the `js_link` option is very handy.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Span, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.line(x=[0,1,2], y=[0,1,2])

vline = Span(location=0, dimension='height', line_color='red', line_width=3)
hline = Span(location=0, dimension='width', line_color='green', line_width=3)
p.renderers.extend([vline, hline])

sv = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=0, step=1, margin=10)
sv.js_link('value', vline, 'location')

sh = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=0, step=1, margin=10)
sh.js_link('value', hline, 'location')

layout = column(sv, sh, p)
show(layout)
```

[image: linked spans]